# Excel 2013 VBA Like condition with colon won't work

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

The value of gettxt = 'ATCH 6: Page 2 of 2

gettxt values are from text formatted cells.

I cannot get the following Like condition to be true.

If LCase(gettxt) Like "*atch #*:" Then ...

Suggestions on how to fix the Like statement are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing one more "*" after the colon.
Your condition states that there shouldn't be anything AFTER the colon, but your "gettxt" value has something in it after that.
So the correct condition should be:

```
If LCase(gettxt) Like "*atch #*:*" Then
```

Full working version:

```
Sub test()

gettxt = "ATCH 6: Page 2 of 2"

If LCase(gettxt) Like "*atch #:*" Then
    Debug.Print "Working!"
Else
    Debug.Print "Not Working!"
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Guess I was focused too much on the colon and had a mental lapse on the wildcard.